# Google Analytics API V4 - Lookup by URL Query

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to use GA API to check if lead submissions are going through our system correctly.

I need to check if pageview has been logged by GA on a url like below:

*www.mysite.com/leads/?e={{email}}

The e= parameter will be a string variable (email address) I pass to my API request, so basically I am checking to see if there is a logged pageview for the passed email.

I have been looking at the GA docs and think I need to use a filter of some kind but a little unsure how to proceed.

Here is my current code, it is simply checking for all todays PageViews without any filter.

```
{
    "reportRequests": [
        {
            "viewId": {{View-ID}},
            "dateRanges": [
                {
                    "startDate": "today",
                    "endDate": "today"
                }
            ],
            "metrics": [
                {
                    "expression": "ga:pageviews"
                }
            ],
            "dimensions":[
                {
                  "name":"ga:date"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello James, just a FYI, email addresses could be considered PIS(https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7686480) and is against GA's TOS.

Consider these solutions if you want to track personal information: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question in a more general sense, you should use [dimension filter clause](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#dimensionfilterclause).

Example:

```
{
"reportRequests": [
    {
        "viewId": {{View-ID}},
        "dateRanges": [
            {
                "startDate": "today",
                "endDate": "today"
            }
        ],
        "metrics": [
            {
                "expression": "ga:pageviews"
            }
        ],
        "dimensions":[
            {
              "name":"ga:date"
            }
        ],
        "dimensionFilterClauses": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                    "dimensionName": "ga:page",
                    "operator": "PARTIAL",
                    "expressions": {{email}}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Many thanks, and also for pointing out the PIS comment, will definitely look into that!

Comment: No problem, I made a typo and it is actually PII for Personally Identifiable Information.